# JavaScript file is not loading properly Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm new in angular 4.
I'm having a problem that I have to refresh my page every time when I navigate to any page to reload my js files and I'm using HTML and CSS template. I put all CSS and JavaScript files link in the Index page. 
here is the code of my index page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <base href="/">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, userscalable=no" name="viewport" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
 <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <!-- Waves Effect Css -->
 <link href="assets/plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <!-- Animation Css -->
 <link href="assets/plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <!-- Morris Chart Css-->
 <link href="assets/plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <!-- Custom Css -->
 <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="theme-red">
 <app-root></app-root>
 <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS and Script files are more than this but here i excluded them just to make thing understandable.
My login page comes first and its design is different from all other pages. when i logged in then i have to refresh the page to load javaScript files after that when i navigate to another page then i have to do the same thing again. 
I'm new so that's why i don't know about the professional terms for this problem.
Here is me app route code

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent
        }
    ]
},

{
    path: 'production',
    component: ProductionComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: ProductionHomeComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'item-registration/fgs',
            component: FgsComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'item-registration/product-details/:id/:productname',
            component: ProductDetailsComponent
        }
    ]

},

];
export const AppRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES);
```

Comment: are you using CLI ?

Comment: yes i'm using angular CLI

Comment: take a look at this on how to load [third party js](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) in Angular  with or without typings

Comment: Ok, i will look on it but I have a question if there is a problem while including third party js then why it is working when i refresh the page?

Comment: it might only work in the initial component but not for all the components of your app

Comment: No, every component start working perfectly when i refresh my that component page but when i navigate to other then new page have same problem but it load some files not all of them